# Inequality for smooth function minus constant in $H^1$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality

Let $I\subset\mathbb{R}$ be an open interval. Let $f\in C^\infty(\bar{I})$.
I need to prove that

$$
\|{f-c}\|_{L^2(I)}\le C h |f|_{H^1(I)}, 
$$
where $c\in\mathbb{R}$ is a suitable constant, $h:=\text{diam}\, I$ and $|\cdot|_{H^1(I)}$ denotes the well-known seminorm.

Comment: The result is false as stated.  Take $c=1$ and $f=0$.

Comment: Okay, I should modify the statement

Comment: Okay, but what does "suitable" mean?  Can we take $c$ to be the average of $f$?

Comment: Yes, I mean that "there exists c such that..."

Comment: Then I don't understand the rest of your post.  You say that you can't choose $c$.  If we take $c$ to be the average of $f$, are we not choosing $c$?

Comment: I forgot to delete something. Now I use Poincaré, but I can't get $h$ on the rhs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $I = (a,a+h)$.  Consider the differentiable function $F:(a,a+h) \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $F(x) = \int_a^x f(y) dy$.  Applying the mean-value theorem to $F$ shows that there exists $z \in (a,a+h)$ such that 
$$
f(z) = F'(z) = \frac{F(a+h) - F(a)}{h}= \frac{1}{h} \int_a^{a+h}f(y) dy. 
$$
Call the right side of this $c$, the average of $f$.  By the fundamental theorem of calculus we have that for any $x \in (a,a+h)$,
$$
\vert f(x) - c \vert = \vert f(x) - f(z) \vert \le \int_{\min\{x,z\}}^{\max\{x,z\}} \vert f'(y)\vert dy \le \int_a^{a+h} \vert f'(y) \vert dy
$$
and so we can use Cauchy-Schwarz to estimate 
$$
\vert f(x) - c \vert^2 \le  h \int_a^{a+h} \vert f'(y)\vert^2 dy.
$$
Now integrate in $x$:
$$
\int_a^{a+h} \vert f(x) -c \vert^2 dx \le h^2 \int_a^{a+h} \vert f'(y)\vert^2 dy,
$$
and your desired estimate follows by taking square roots.